# How to install PagedList.Mvc reference in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I tried to install PagedList.Mvc in Nuget Package manager console by

> PM > Install-Package PagedList.Mvc

But geting **error** like below:

> Install-Package : Unable to find package 'PagedList.Mvc'. 
> At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package PagedList.Mvc
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

So I installed through **Manage Nuget packages for solution** from online.

But the problem is I need to install from online for every projects through 'Manage Nuget packages for solution'.
Is there any way to get installed permanently in reference folder for every projects that I created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to get installed permanently in reference folder for
>   every projects that i created..?

Install it for solution and so if there is multiple project present, `NuGet` UI will show that and you can check/select the projects for which you want to install it.

Later if you create another project under that solution, you will have to install it separately.

I am not that sure what you exactly mean by `permanently`?

To install `NuGet` package use the UI. Right click on solution and select `Manage NuGet package for solution`. That will bring the UI. Click on Browse tab -> select the package and Go on from there.

Comment: Permanently means it should be present in reference ,if I created another solution later..how  it can be done.?

Comment: @Abhi, No, that can't be done. If you create another solution tomorrow, you need to install it from NuGet again.

Comment: Is there any other way to get rid of this problem Rahul..?Or installation every time is only a optional.?

Comment: If that package is needed then you will have to install it explicitly. There is no alternative as far I know off.

Comment: May I know how Explicitly..?Because i ran command 'Install-Package PagedList.Mvc' in console as mentioned above in question,but no use..

Answer (score 0):

Write in package manager console

PM> Install-Package PagedList.Mvc

link here
https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc/